# Can't install FLUXION 5.9 dependency “mdk4” on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I want to install Fluxion 5.9 on ubuntu 18.04 with its dependencies but I'm facing problems with the package "mdk4" and the installation aborts after many warnings and `make: *** [install] Error 127`.

```
apt-get install pkg-config libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libpcap-dev
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/mdk4
cd mdk4
make
sudo make install
```

Installation fails with many errors and warnings :

```
channelhopper.c: In function ‘init_channel_hopper’:
channelhopper.c:592:19: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int lpos = 0, i;
                   ^
At top level:
channelhopper.c:240:14: warning: ‘dfs_state_name’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static char *dfs_state_name(enum nl80211_dfs_state state)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=mdk4-v1  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra    -c -o ghosting.o ghosting.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=mdk4-v1  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra    -c -o fragmenting.o fragmenting.c
make -C attacks
make[2]: Entering directory '/mdk4/src/attacks'
cc -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra   -c -o attacks.o attacks.c
attacks.c: In function ‘load_attacks’:
attacks.c:8:29: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   struct attacks *attacks = malloc(sizeof(struct attacks) * attack_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this prior to the make and make install

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev ethtool shtool rfkill zlib1g-dev libpcap-dev libsqlite3-dev libpcre3-dev libhwloc-dev libcmocka-dev hostapd wpasupplicant tcpdump screen iw usbutils clang
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/mdk4
cd mdk4
sudo make
sudo make install
```

sudo is not necessary for the make part, only the make install part but I use sudo for make to ensure no errors occur as some compilations fail without it.

I just did this on my ubuntu 18.04 and it worked fine. Fluxion detected it as installed after these steps and everything is working smoothly with the RTL8812AU chipset using the RTL8812AU DKMS kernel module installed.